# Redirecting to original url after authentication in PassportJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I am trying to access the URL `http://localhost:3000/users#/WyCrYc28r/foo/1414585518343`, but a user needs to be authenticated before he/she could access that path as shown below:

```
app.get('/users', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
      req.session.user = req.user;
      res.cookie('uid', req.session.passport.user)
          .render('users', { title: 'The Foo Machine', user: req.user });
  });
```

The `isLoggedIn` middleware is used as following for finding out if the user is authenticated:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
      return next();
  res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Anf following is how a request to login is being handled using PassportJS:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/users', 
    failureRedirect: '/login', 
    failureFlash: true 
}));
```

But I do not want the user to go to `/users` after logging in successfully. I want the user to go back to the its original URL (`http://localhost:3000/users#/WyCrYc28r/foo/1414585518343`) that he/she was trying to access.

I am using the `LocalStrategy` for authentication/autheorization using PassportJS.
Could somebody help me with it?

Comment: You can't because everything after the `#` isn't sent to the server.

Comment: @idbehold: Isn't there any work around? I am actually using AngularJS in the front end and I can't have the `html5Mode` mode turned on. Hence, the `#`.

Comment: Why not simply render the login page on /users if the user isn't authenticated? Then you can submit the form via XHR, and since it won't be cross-domain that means cookies will always be sent. If the server responds successfully it will set the session cookie and you can then call `location.reload(true)` and everything should just work.